# optimize the mysql query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, query-optimization

I have following mysql query which is taking long time(40s) to load the results.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS blog_posts.ID FROM blog_posts 
LEFT JOIN blog_term_relationships AS tt0 ON (blog_posts.ID = tt0.object_id) 
LEFT JOIN blog_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (blog_posts.ID = tt1.object_id) 
LEFT JOIN blog_term_relationships AS tt2 ON (blog_posts.ID = tt2.object_id) 
LEFT JOIN blog_term_relationships AS tt3 ON (blog_posts.ID = tt3.object_id) 
WHERE 1=1  
AND ( ( tt0.term_taxonomy_id IN (141,177) AND tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (2389,2390) ) 
OR ( tt2.term_taxonomy_id IN (167,1169,1715) AND tt3.term_taxonomy_id IN (2519,2520) ) ) 
AND blog_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (blog_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY blog_posts.ID ORDER BY blog_posts.post_date ASC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Is there any way to optimize this query.

**Edit:**

This is related to `wordpress` and this query was automatically create from the `wp_query`.

Table structures as bellow,

`blog_posts` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `blog_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_ping` text NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=125636 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

`blog_term_relationships` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `blog_term_relationships` (
  `object_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `term_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`object_id`,`term_taxonomy_id`),
  KEY `term_taxonomy_id` (`term_taxonomy_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

EXPLAIN QUERY:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zz5j2.jpg)

Comment: Questions about query performance should include table structures `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]` and `EXPLAIN [query]`

Comment: why you are using group by without aggregation function?   .. and why you have l columns related  to left joined  tables in where clause  ? .. these should work as inner .. join  ...

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have updated the question

Comment: @scaisEdge not sure about it as this is automatically created by wp_query

Comment: WHERE 1=1  ?? That's allways TRUE, you can remove it and only use the rest of the WHERE clause

Comment: @nacho - WordPress automatically adds that for internal purposes.

Comment: **Note:** You cannot modify queries in WordPress.  The `$wpdb` is deeply wired in, and does not expose hooks that will allow modifying this query.  Your problem is almost certainly related to indexes being missing.

Comment: @cale_b my plan is to use direct queries as I can't change the `wp_query`

Comment: @cale_b it is already been indexed as you can see in the table description.

Comment: EXPLAIN don't match the query since blog_term_relationships table is not there. Also, are there indexes on `post_date, post_status and post_type`?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz it is there with tt0,tt1.. and yes all those fields are indexed.

Comment: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS could be one of the reasons, did you tried removing it?. You could try using UNION ALL to move the OR condition to its own SELECT and see if that helps.

Comment: `1=1` is a sign of lazy programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reformulate**

```
SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS blog_posts.ID
    FROM  ( 
            (
                SELECT  object_id
                    FROM  blog_term_relationships AS tt0
                    JOIN  blog_term_relationships AS tt1 USING(object_id)
                    WHERE  tt0.term_taxonomy_id IN (141,177)
                      AND  tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (2389,2390)

            )
        UNION DISTINCT
            (
                SELECT  object_id
                    FROM  blog_term_relationships AS tt2
                    JOIN  blog_term_relationships AS tt3 USING(object_id)
                    WHERE  tt2.term_taxonomy_id IN (167,1169,1715)
                      AND  tt3.term_taxonomy_id IN (2519,2520) ) 
          ) AS tt
    JOIN  blog_posts  ON blog_posts.ID = tt.object_id
    WHERE  blog_posts.post_type = 'post'
      AND  blog_posts.post_status = 'publish'
    ORDER BY  blog_posts.post_date ASC
    LIMIT  0, 20
```

This gets rid of the `GROUP BY` and does several other things to speed up the query.

**Prefix index**

```
`post_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=125636 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Make up your mind -- 191 is for version 5.6 with utf8mb4 (which you have not specified); 191 is so close to 200, you may as well make it `VARCHAR(191)`.  Getting rid of the prefix index is likely to speed up some of your queries.

**InnoDB**

Don't use MyISAM, move to InnoDB.  That is for performance, robustness, etc.  That will coincidentally fix an inefficiency in `KEY term_taxonomy_id)`.

**SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS**

SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is costly.  It's purpose is passe.